# Galaxy S5 unlock + change region

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sim-unlocking

I have an stock, locked, Telstra Australian Galaxy S5 and I'm about to live in the UK.

I would like to know if there is currently a way to unlock it without code so I can use it with an English carrier.

I've searched a lot about this but results are highly polluted with commercial links.

Thank you

Comment: I'll look around, but newer samsung firmwares often do need a paid unlock code. Your network may send you one if you explain your situation to them.

Comment: Ok thank you that's too bad, I'm a very recent customer so they won't give me a code.